# ImageResizer (DiskCache) don't work

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer, with Remote reader and Diskcache, and I'm having problems with the Diskcache.

I did all the configuration that is recomended [in documentation](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/diskcache).

This is how my configuration is:

```
<resizer>
        <remotereader signingKey="mySigningKey" allowAllSignedRequests="true" allowRedirects="5" />
        <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="true" enabled="true" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" syncBufferSize="10485760" />
        <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />
        <plugins>
            <add name="RemoteReader" />
            <add name="DiskCache" />
        </plugins>
</resizer>
```

And I have a simple code to do the job:

```
    using ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache;
    using ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader;

    string setting = new ResizeSettings("width=200&height=100").ToString();
    string myImage= RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrlWithKey("someImageUrl", setting, "mySigningKey");
```

Is missing something in my code to make DiskCache working, or is any problem with my configuration?

Comment: Are you getting error messages (compile- or run-time)?  `It doesn't work` isn't very helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely right, _It doesn't work_ isn't helpfull, but I dont receive any message, that's why I'm going crazy!

Comment: How far in the process is it getting?  Does it not even write to disk?

Comment: Do not write on the disc, with the code that I have only generates me the path to the image Processed, like : `/remote.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=100&urlb64=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudW55ay50di9pbWFnZXMvc3Rvcmllcy9mbGV4aWNvbnRlbnQvbF91bmtjaGFubmVsX2JnX3R2LTEuanBn&hmac=5JrPws8mx1w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time testing I realized the error was cacheAccessTimeout then increased the time but still continued to error , so I made a new soluction with the same configurations and now works flawlessly.